# Access INFORMATION_SCHEMA in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to check in which table a certain column exists. This should be done by the application during runtime.  I wanted to do that with the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table and a WHERE statement. When I execute the query I made in pgAdmin it works. Now how can I access this table in Rails? Or is there a better way to do what I want?

This is the query I made:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'myColumn'
order by TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the **rails console**

```
rails c
```

Here you can run your Model methods, including `Model.column_names` that will give you the column names of your Model.

If you need to find all the names of your models, you can run in the rails console the following:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.map do |model|
  model.capitalize.singularize.camelize
end
```

That will give you all the Model names.

Another way is the **rails db console**

```
rails db
```

Here you can run SQL statements.

### Edit

Supouse you have a *column_name* called `fighting` and you want to know if it is a column name of a Model,
and if it is you want to know the Model.

If that is the scenario, you can do this:

```
@column_name = 'fighting'   #the column that you want to search
@find_it = 'not found'
array_model = []

#find all the Model names
array_model = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.map do |model|
  model.capitalize.singularize.camelize
end

array_model.delete_if{|i|i=='SchemaMigration'} #Remove the SchemaMigration

#Get the `column_names` of every Model, and check if is the name that you are searching
array_model.each do |model|
    tmp = eval model + ".column_names" 
    tmp.each {|col| @find_it = model if col == @column_name} 
end
```

There you will have your table name in `@find_it`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I'll edit to make it clearer. I want my Application to check this during runtime. It gets a string from an input and should then search for a table.

Comment: So what you want is to enter a table name, and check if that table exists?

Comment: No, I want to enter a column name and then check in which tables a column with that name exists

Comment: @Smoenybfan See if this is what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If raw query is working you can execute it with **`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`**

```
def find_tables_for(column_name)
  return unless column_name
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
    "SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
     WHERE COLUMN_NAME = '#{column_name}'
     ORDER BY TABLE_NAME"
  ).values.flatten
end

$~ find_tables_for('user_id')
#=> ["profiles", "posts"]
```

This method will return all the tables which has the column_name

> **Note**: I am intentionally selecting only `table_name` you can add other fields as well